# Update permissions for Azure DevOps group for EventSubscription through Azure CLI?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I've been adding permissions to a custom Azure DevOps Services group through the Azure CLI (az devops version 0.11.0) and I've usually been able to do the following:

1. `az devops security permission namespace list`, find namespaceId of specific namespace (like EventSubscription)
2. Get the Project Admin's descriptor
3. `az devops security permission list --id $namespaceId --subject $projectAdmin.descriptor`...
4. Find an allow bit in the ACES dictionary, find the respective token
5. `az devops security permission update`... with the new token

But when I run security permission list for the EventSubscription namespace, it returns with empty JSON for the project admins group so I can't find the token. I've tried "$SUBSCRIPTION" as it looked like what a TFS 2010 user used, but that doesn't work.

Questions:

1. How can I list tokens on the project admins group for the EventSubscription namespace? I tried to see if tfssecurity would pull anything up, but didn't work. Also tried using Fiddler to see if it would find a token but also nothing. Can't use Fiddler with the UI.
2. Or what token do I use for Azure DevOps to update the EventSubscription permission for a group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested with `EventSubscription` namespace id and `project admins group` descriptor as `subject` parameters and got the same result as you.

[image]

```
$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'ckdhd6wuma5uw2h35dv37pgdum5eyjviqneineixxxxx'

$output = az devops security permission namespace list | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

#get descriptor
$output2 = az devops security group list --scope project | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

#eventSubscription namespaceId: 58b176e7-3411-457a-89d0-c6xxx/ Project namespaceId:52d39943-cb85-4d7f-8fa8-c6xxx
$output3 = az devops security permission list --namespace-id 58b176e7-3411-457a-89d0-c6xxxx --subject vssgp.Uy0xLTktMTU1MTM3NDI0NS00MjQ3MDQ2OTMyLTI2ODA1Nzg2MjktMjkxMzgyMjE4MC0yNDQ0MjYxxxxx | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Write-Host $output3
```

But when I tested with `Project` namespace id and `project admins group` descriptor, I can get the token normally.

[image]

So I think this could be a problem with the association between the `EventSubscription` namespace and the `project admins group` descriptor. Can you share the corresponding operation in the UI? This will help me investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out too - according to the docs, there isn't a way to add notifications through the UI (otherwise I would have tried Fiddler). I think I did try Fiddler with TFSSecurity and that didn't show up with anything. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#notifications-or-alerts